# How to read ViewData value of type DateTime in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 project. In my controller method, I have a ViewData which is assigned by a value of type DateTime. Now in my razor view I need its value in a javascript function. I appreciate if anyone helps me regarding the issue.

What I have till now is using:

```
<script>
    var datePart = @Html.Raw(ViewData["projectStartDate"]);
</script>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to inject the date value as a string, then parse it in the script as a JavaScript `Date` value. It would be better to provide this as a strongly-typed view model, but if you need to use ViewData for some reason, an example:

```
@{
    // Get the .NET DateTime from ViewData, convert to ISO string
    string dateString = "";
    if (ViewData["projectStartDate"] is DateTime date)
    {
        dateString = date.ToString("O");
    }
}

...

<script>
    // Parse into JavaScript value
    var datejs = Date.parse("@dateString");
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand what is 0 in date.ToString("O");. It displays to me an error.

Comment: It's a format specifier to create a string in "round-trip" format (ISO 8601). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#table-of-format-specifiers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The format of ViewData["projectStartDate"] in controller is 2021-10-05 10:58:56.000. after using your suggestion datejs will show me a number like 2347565...

Comment: Yes, that's how JavaScript represents dates. You can format it however you want. Not sure what is the question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean I want the javascript variable also shows me the format correctly like 2021-10-05 10:58:56.000. How can I convert the datejs value format like the above I mentioned?